# Replace / Delete everything after first + character in datastudio

Tags: regex, google-analytics, looker-studio, regexp-replace, re2

I have a string looking like this (stored as an Event Action value from Google Analytics)

```
0+171235652++zu
```

or

```
122+115166747++en
```

I would like (with the use of calculate fields) create a new field that will show only the number before the 1st '+' character. So in those examples above

0 or 122

What I tried was (below), but it did not help, Any ideas?

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(Event Action, '(^\\+).*', '')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Event Action, '^([^+]+)')
```

See the [regex in action](https://regex101.com/r/aKwD1i/1). The regex matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `([^+]+)` - Capturing group 1: any one or more chars other than a `+` (you may use `([^+]*)` if you want to also get empty match when a `+` is the first char).

If you want a replacement function, you may use

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(Event Action,"[+].*","")
```

Answer (score 1):

The pattern you tried `(^\\+).*` did not work because this part `^\\+` matches the start of the string followed by 1 or more times a plus sign.

---

If what comes before the first plus sign should be digits and the plus sign itself should be present, you could capture the leading digits followed by matching the plus sign followed by the rest of the string.

Use group 1 using `\\1` in the replacement.

```
^(\\d+)\\+.*
```

*In parts*

- `^` Start of string
- `(\\d+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1 or more digits
- `\\+.*` Match a `+` char and 0 or more times any char except a newline

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RcHWnn/1)

*Example code*

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(Event Action, '^(\\d+)\\+.*', '\\1')
```